# Laravel 4 ManyToMany where

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

- products (->belongsToMany('Series'))
- series (->belongsToMany('Product'))
- product_series

If I want to take products with series = 3:

```
Series::find(3)->products;
```

Produced sql query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `product_series`
ON `products`.`id` = `product_series`.`product_id`
WHERE `product_series`.`series_id` = '3'
```

The question is how can I take products where **series_id != 3** with Eloquent?
The sql query is smth like:

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `product_series`
ON `products`.`id` = `product_series`.`product_id`
WHERE `product_series`.`series_id` != '3'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
$series = Series::where('id', '!=', 3)->with('products')->get();
```

Comment: never ever use this, very slow query with IN except 3 (imagine 100 or 1000 IN)